# Prove that $\{2k+5 \mid k\in \mathbb{Z}\} = \{2k+3 \mid k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Prove that $\{2k+5 \mid k\in \mathbb{Z}\} = \{2k+3 \mid k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

I know how to do $\{2k+5 | k\in \mathbb{Z}\} \subset \{2k+3 \mid k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

What I'm having trouble doing is proving $\{2k+3 \mid k\in \mathbb{Z}\} \subset \{2k+5 \mid k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

To start, I can say that

$a = 2k+3$

and I know I should probably end up with something like

$a = 2(m+1)+3$

$a = 2m+2+3$

$a = 2m+5$

and then $ a\in\{2k+5 \mid k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

I'm just iffy on how to get here. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To turn the $3$ into a $5$, we need to donate a $2$ from the first term, which suggests that we should subtract one to compensate. Indeed, given any $k \in \mathbb Z$, observe that:
$$
2k + 3 = 2((k - 1) + 1) + 3 = 2(k - 1) + 2 + 3 = 2\underbrace{(k - 1)}_{\in ~ \mathbb Z} + 5
$$
as desired.

Answer (score 1):

All you should need to do is show that each element in the first set is in the second set:

> For each $2k+5$ in the first set note that $2(k+1)+3=2k+5$ is in the second set.

and show that each element in the second set is in the first set:

> For each $2k+3$ in the second set note that $2(k-1)+5=2k+3$ is in the first set.